# Get full date range of linked field in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

[Gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3FPM.gif)

I am currently working on a dashboard in tableau, which shows the count of New-User-Signups and Interactions side-by-side given different date windows. The first New-User-Signup happened before the first Interaction, and the last Interaction happened after the last User Signup.

In order to choose a date window, I linked the date fields in both data sources, and made a date filter, which I applied to all worksheets using related data sources.

However, depending on which "date" field I choose, (from the User Signup table or the Interaction table), the "All Dates" option of the date filter only goes from start to end of *that* data source's date range.

No matter what I try, I exclude some entries in either one graph or the other. How can I make the "All Dates" filter go from the minimum first date between both data sources, to the maximum last date between the two data sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this issue a lot with the data that I use. The problem is that the filter will only be able to contain dates that are in the dataset it is created off of, even if you link the data sources. When I run into this issue, I use parameters instead.

You can find instructions here: 
https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-filter-for-start-and-end-dates-parameters